# App behaves differently on iOS device vs iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

forgive me if asking the wrong question - I'm new to coding.
I have my app running correctly on iPad Air 2 simulator, however when deployed to my actual iPad Air 2, one line of code (as far as I can tell) doesn't work.

The line in question -

```
starArray[streakCounter-1].image = UIImage(named: "22.png")
```

The line is part of an if statement in which all other lines work just fine on the device and simulator.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: As far as I can tell, it just doesn't execute. It's supposed to change an image  view's image to "22.png" after the same image view runs a sprite animation. It works in the simulator, but on the device the animation plays and then it returns to its initial image instead of the new image.

Comment: Is that line of code even called on a device? What is the actual result of calling `UIImage(named: "22.png")` on a device? BTW - you don't need the `.png` when using `UIImage(named:)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just cleaned that up. I assumed if it was called on the simulator it would also be called on the device. It doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: First you need to be specific. *"doesn't seem to do anything"* is far too vague. Is the line of code being called or not on a device? Use the debugger if you don't know for sure. See exactly what happens. If it is being called, split the line into two. `let image = UIImage(named: "22.png")` followed by `starArray[streakCounter-1].image = image`. Confirm whether `image` is `nil` or not.

Comment: Apologies if this is moving off the topic of the question, but how do I see if the line is being called on the device? I'm not familiar with the debugger yet.

Comment: Using the debugger is how you check. Teaching how to use the debugger is beyond the scope of a comment here. I'm sure you can find plenty of tutorials on using the Xcode debugger in a Swift/iOS app. One hint: breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of cases where the simulator behaves differently than an actual device.

The file system is one of those cases. The Mac OS file system is not case-sensitive by default (unless you take extra steps in setting up a drive). The iOS file system **is** case-sensitive. The simulator runs on the Mac file system.

If your file is really called "22.PNG" or "22.Png" then your code would work on the sim but not on a device.

I don't know for sure if that's the cause of your problem, but it's at least worth checking.

(There are other differences as well, but I focused on the one that seems most likely to cause the problem you describe.)

Comment: Just checked the file names hoping this was the source of the problem but sadly not! Is there anything else I might try?

Comment: So break your code into 2 statements, the first of which puts the results into a temporary variable of type `UIImage`, and then step through your code in the debugger. See if the call to `UIImage(named:)` is returning nil.